# How to send email from distribution list using C# and Microsoft Exchange Service API?

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have the following problem:

1. In Exchange admin center ("https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com/") I have created a group of type "Distribution list" with an email "info@mycompany.com"
2. Using the Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices API I need to send an email with sender "info@mycompany.com"
3. In my app when I make the Exchange connection - I use the list email "info@mycompany.com" as "ImpersonatedUserId" with "ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress"
4. When I run my C# test console app it gives me the error "The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it.

If I run my app with shared mailbox instead - it works fine. But when I try to send with the distribution list - I get the error.

Is it possible to use the distribution list email as a sender? Does this list have a mailbox which can be used?

Thanks

Comment: A distribution list has no mailbox and cannot be used to send mail messages. You would need to convert it to a `mail-enabled security group` or create a new one under the Mail-enabled security tab within [Groups](https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com/#/groups)

Comment: Mail-enabled security group doesn't work either. Seems the only possible way is through shared mailbox.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. The only alternatives I can think of would be a resource mailbox like a room mailbox, or a M365 group, but a shared mailbox would be the best option probably.